# Oculus SDK Huge Chromatic Abberations (produced by program!)

Tags: oculus

I have red-blue-coloured edges.
It is bad for me.
How to configure SDK to get rid of it?

I started samples (Tiny room).
But shaders are somewhere else (possibly in dll, so I cant fix them).

edit 1)
Tiny room demo is working.
I have unpleasant effect of distortion that made by **program**. 
It is aimed to prevent chromatic abberation, but it make it worse.

Or I need some kind of red-blue glasses in addition to Oculus ? (it's ridiculus, but I must to ask)

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. Do you have trouble using the SDK to output a correctly chroma-distorted image to the headset? Do you think there is an error in the SDK? Does the OculusTinyRoom work for you or not?

Comment: For the record you just have to render your view normally, the runtime will handle distortion and chromatic aberration itself.

Comment: @JoanCharmant , I edited post to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two bad solution.
1) The problem can be solved by using different copy of the product.
2) There is also possibility of switching off the **whole** image distortion in Oculus SDK in modules which contain OpenGL- or DirectX-specific commands.(but it also disables the barrel distortion)